# Convert FPDF output to base64 string

Tags: php, api, base64, fpdf

I am working with the PHP API where I need to create the PDF file using the FPDF and then I wanted to save it to the database by converting it to the base64 string. When I have tried the default `$pdf->Output()` method then I got the PDF file in my postman response.
Then I have tried to use this line of code to encode the pdf to base64 format. It worked but I am getting the broken pdf when I decode the base64 string.

```
$pdfFile = $pdf->Output("","S");
$base64String = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfFile));
```

Am i doing anything wrong with this? Any small help would be appriciated.

Comment: Why use `chunk_split()`?